# Yii wrong encoding(UTF-8) in searchForm Lable

Tags: php, yii, encoding, utf-8, diacritics

I have a problem in my view fromm SearchForm in a Yii Project.
In the lables there are `<?> <?>` instead of "ä,ö,ü" but this error is only in the searchForm, the rest of the page works fine.

The file is correctly saved in UTF-8 and the Utf 8 Charset is also set in Header of the Main.php and the same aplies for the DB.

Has anyone an idea for a solution?
Many thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: try add in index.php file `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',true);`

Comment: I added the code-line but it still not work, the confusing thing is that the rest of the page encodes right, the search form is only a php file witch is included in the midle of the page...

Answer (score 0):

Check the

```
Apache configuration (in httpd.conf or .htaccess)
```

Whether its UTF8 or Windows 1252

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
PHP (in php.ini)

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
mbstring.internal_encoding=utf-8
mbstring.http_output=UTF-8
mbstring.encoding_translation=On
mbstring.func_overload=6
```

also use `mb_detect_encoding`  for debugging to check where the data gets currupted

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Comment: okey the Apache is right, and theresult of mb_detect_encoding is "UTF 8"... I dont know where the error come's from.

Comment: Then may be the issue is with connector encoding  I am not really sure. I dont knw which server you are using so can't comment on that.